# How to deal with a database in Android's Tab Activity

Tags: android, sql, database, tabs

So I have an Android app that is running in a TabActivity that separates 3 different activities through this tabs. I've set a DatabaseHandler class with SQLite and all, fine.

The thing is, so far I don't really know how to deal with the database since it will be receiving data from one of the activities and I need to be showing that data in a different one. I don't know if I should declare the db in the main TabActivity or where, I've never worked with SQL in Android before and I'm pretty lost at the moment.

I tried to picture it so it is more understandable: [Explanatory Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11xDC.png) (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation yet to post the image into the post directly)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be okay, as long as you close your connection with the database as soon as you're done reading/writing to the database.

Each activity should be able to have their own DatabaseHandler.

Comment: I understand from you that the database remains always the same regardless of which tab I'm in as long as I declare a DatabaseHandler in all of them. Sorry but as I said I'm new to this, I was worried the database could only serve me for a single activity or that I could create multiple different databases for each one without being aware of it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem! The database is written to disk when you call `close()`, so SQLite should take care of the concurrency issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although using your DatabaseHandler is posssible within each activity in the long term I think most non-trivial apps would benefit from using a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html%20ContentProvider)

`ContentProvider` provides an abstraction over your data. It becomes really powerful when you combine it with a [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) and [`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html%20LoaderManager) available back to Android 1.6 by using the support library.

These concepts require a bit of study but will make sharing data across multiple Fragment or Activities simpler and less error prone.

Mobile Tuts has a couple of good tutorials that are worth reading on top of the official Android documentation and examples:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Comment: Thanks! I will give a look to that but I really needed to save it into a SQLite database since that was what I was asked to do! ;)